# Impact of enabling bridged mode on upstream router

Tags: router, bridge-router

My ISP (Comcast xFinity) supplies [a WiFi enabled router](http://ciscodocs.technicolor.com/web/consumer/pdf/OL-29163-01.pdf) that has very limited functionality. I have an Asus RT-AC68U connected to this router which handles my WiFi. There are no other real clients beyond my Asus router.

I'd like to expose the Asus router directly to the internet so that I can enable access to internal resources. This is problematic right now because I have a hierarchical config with my internal network for the Asus, and an outer network for the Comcast router.

I found a setting to enable Bridge Mode on the Comcast router. I'm most familiar with this when I'm doing something like using a WiFi extender.

[image: Bridge mode configuration screen on DPC3939]

Can I enable this Bridge Mode at the upstream router to transparently promote my Asus router to the edge of my network? Or, will this typically disable other networking features that end up blocking my connection. I'm happy to hear the generic networking answer for this and give it a go since my Comcast router isn't something everyone will have experience with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave this a shot and it seems to work. A key thing that I [discovered](http://forums.xfinity.com/t5/Your-Home-Network/Cisco-XB3-DPC3939-bridge-mode/td-p/2580241) was that that only port 1 is activated on the DPC3939 router when in Bridged Mode.

[image: DPC3939 Bridged Mode warning]

My Asus router now has the public IP address, and the Comcast router is accessible at http://10.0.0.1 if I need to perform admin tasks on it.